# How should I upgrade both 2sxc and its old version Blog App?

Tags: upgrade, blogs, 2sxc

I have an install with 2sxc 12.4 and using the Blog 4 app. I customized the template and CSS of the Blog app in the past. I'd like to upgrade 2sxc to the latest version, 16, but doing that on a test copy of the install broke the Blog app. I find myself getting confused about how to get both 2sxc and the Blog app (now available in version 5) upgraded, and the blog articles transferred to the new blog version if that's not an actual "upgrade". Can anyone help or point me to the correct resources? I've been searching the 2sxc.org docs but am not yet finding what I think I need.

Thanks!!

- I tried directly installing 2sxc 16. The Blog 4 list displayed correctly, but the article detail just showed the yellow error message block.
- I tried installing the Blog 5 through 2sxc. It installed in parallel with Blog 4 vs. being an upgrade.
- I tried exporting the blog articles from Blog 4 and importing them into Blog 5. The export/import completed, but Blog 5 now showed the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no just-install-the-latest-app upgrade path.

The reason is twofold:

1. the installed Apps are often customized in so many possible ways (eg. changes to what fields exist, new content-types, new settings, changes to the output) that a direct upgrade would never be able to handle this
2. the template-apps which get published also have many changes to keep up with latest development

The recommended upgrade path is

1. Install a new app in parallel - usually major versions are in a separate folder, allowing multiple versions to be installed
2. Compare the functionality to decide what you want
3. Then either manually copy the latest razor parts that you like
4. ...or use list-export-import to sync data. You will often need to edit the exported data in excel to match the new schema.

Comment: Thanks so much, Daniel! (and for taking time to respond to this on Towel-day eve, even!) I'm still wrapping my head around the 2sxc ecosystem. There's so much potential. This helps.